# Removing OpenVPN and all modifications

Tags: networking, server, openvpn

When starting up my server takes a long time. I already tried `sudo apt-get remove openvpn` but somewhere it's still trying to setup OpenVPN. When I connect to the server I get all these internal VPN addresses:

```
System load:          0.02                IP address for as0t3:  5.5.3.1
Usage of /:           13.5% of 212.98GB   IP address for as0t4:  5.5.4.1
Memory usage:         4%                  IP address for as0t5:  5.5.5.1
Swap usage:           0%                  IP address for as0t6:  5.5.6.1
Processes:            164                 IP address for as0t7:  5.5.7.1
Users logged in:      0                   IP address for as0t8:  5.5.8.1
IP address for eth0: my_ip_here           IP address for as0t9:  5.5.9.1
IP address for as0t0: 5.5.0.1             IP address for as0t10: 5.5.10.1
IP address for as0t1: 5.5.1.1             IP address for as0t11: 5.5.11.1
IP address for as0t2: 5.5.2.1
```

When I check `/etc/networking/interfaces` it is empty.

```
root@ubuntu:~# ls -l /etc/openvpn
total 12
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Mar 11 22:27 easy-rsa
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  636 Dec  6 18:35 static.key
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 1357 Feb 26  2013 update-resolv-conf
root@ubuntu:~# dpkg -l | grep vpn
rc  openvpn                             2.2.1-8ubuntu1.2                            virtual private network daemon
ii  openvpn-as                          1.8.4-Ubuntu10                              openvpn-as
```

Comment: Post the output of `dpkg -l | grep vpn` and `ls -l /etc/openvpn`.

Comment: @EricCarvalho I added them to the bottom of the question

Comment: `sudo apt-get purge openvpn*`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
sudo systemctl disable openvpn --now # on modern distros with systemd
```

Will remove OpenVPN service from startup and stop it

But if you cannot find the init script that is starting the `openvpn` process you can simply  remove or rename these `.conf` files under `/etc/openvpn/` since they generate the VPN interface and routes.

Comment: I don't have the package `update-rc` & `apt-get install update-rc` doesn't work.

Comment: ah updated the command name, in the answer